# Deploy large artifect for static site

Tags: next.js, devops, gatsby, static-site

I'm developing a website backed by a static site generator which will build about 100K static HTML pages. Currently, my workflow is building the project on my local machine, and use an FTP tool to upload the output folder (about 40G) from my local machine to a remote production server, which is a long and painful uploading process, which could take about 24 hours.

I'm wondering if there's a recommended way to set up a better build & deployment process to make it faster and more automated?

Answer (score 0):

With an extremely large number of pages, build times have been the crux of static-site generators. The solution is to defer generating some pages from build time to request time.

For example, you can only [statically generate](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#static-generation-with-data) the top 10,000 most requested at build time to keep your build times low. Then, at *request time* you can use [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) and [Incremental Static Regeneration](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#incremental-static-regeneration) to build static pages.

Let's say a request comes in for one of the other 90,000 pages you haven't statically generated. Instead of getting a static site, the first request will hit the server to fetch the data and generate the static page. Then, that page is cached. When another person visits this page, they will see the static page (which is much faster than talking directly to the server).

You can also invalidate the cache using the [`revalidate` flag](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation). For example, you could make your page fetch new information every minute using `revalidate: 60`.

Deploying a Next.js app to [Vercel](https://vercel.com) using this setup should reduce your build & deploy times to less than 10 minutes, while still creating a performant static site. Simply `git push` to your repository and the [GitHub integration](https://vercel.com/github) will build and deploy your application for you. No more FTP!

Answer (score 0):

Gatsby recently added a feature to fix this (or to try to), which is [called incremental builds](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/cloud/docs/incremental-builds/). Basically, it caches all your data and it will redeploy the changed files and the code changes.

Actually, it seems a feature restricted to Gatsby Cloud or other CMS, not available for a custom deploy server. Here's an example to achieve it in [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2020/04/23/enable-gatsby-incremental-builds-on-netlify/).

Before these recent changes in Gatsby's policy, you only need to add an environment variable to your command deploy:

```
GATSBY_EXPERIMENTAL_PAGE_BUILD_ON_DATA_CHANGES=true gatsby build
```

Keep in mind that this option is not suitable for all deployment servers. If you are regenerating your `/public` folder in each build from scratch it won't work.

Another option is to use a huge S3 machine of Amazon and kill it once the deploy is done.